# Calculate sum of list within a Map of Map

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of Trades that is a map of map grouped by Region and Status. Trade class has an attribute amount field.

```
Map<Region, Map<Status, List<Trade>>> groupedTrades

class Trade {
  double amount;
}
```

I want to group the amounts across Trades within the list and return it as below

```
Map<Region, Map<Status, Double>> sumOfGroupedTradeAmounts
```

Double is a sum of all the amount fields within the list of trades.

How can I do this is in java8?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Map<Region, Double> sumOfGroupedTradeAmounts = groupedTrades.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> calcTotal(e.getValue())));  I am able to do it with a single map, I am not sure how to get it working when I have a Map of Map

Comment: A way can be nested toMap and then sum in value like `groupedTrades.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                t -> t.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(i -> i.getAmount()).sum()))));`

Comment: Add your tried code in your post rather in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Basically, you are:

- Doing nested streaming of the entrySets.
- Stream the outer map entries to get the inner map values and the outer map key.
- in the inner entry set, stream the value, which is the `List<Doubles>` and sum them.
- these are then returned in the specified map using the outer map key, inner map key and a sum of the Trade amounts resulting in a double value.

Note that I added a getter to the `Trade` class for `amount` retrieval.

```
class Trade {
    double amount;
    
    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Region, Map<Status, Double>> result = groupedTrades
            .entrySet().stream()

            // outer map starts here, keying on Region
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e
                    .getValue().entrySet().stream()

                     // inner map starts here, keying on Status
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,

                           // stream the list and sum the amounts.
                            ee -> ee.getValue().stream()
                                    .mapToDouble(Trade::getAmount)
                                    .sum()))));
    
}
```

Given the following structure where `Region` and `Status` are `numbers` and `letters` respectively,

```
Map<Region, Map<Status, List<Trade>>> groupedTrades = Map.of(   
        new Region(1),                                          
        Map.of(new Status("A"),                                 
                List.of(new Trade(10), new Trade(20),           
                        new Trade(30)),                         
                new Status("B"),                                
                List.of(new Trade(1), new Trade(2))),           
        new Region(2),                                          
        Map.of(new Status("A"),                                 
                List.of(new Trade(2), new Trade(4),             
                        new Trade(6)),                          
                new Status("B"), List.of(new Trade(3),          
                        new Trade(6), new Trade(9))));

result.forEach((k, v) -> {                           
    System.out.println(k);                           
    v.forEach((kk, vv) -> System.out                 
            .println("     " + kk + " -> " + vv));   
});
```

Here is the sample output.

```
2
     B -> 18.0
     A -> 12.0
1
     B -> 3.0
     A -> 60.0
```

If you're interested in suming `all` of the values. you can do it as follows by using the just created nested map of doubles.

```
double allSums =
         // Stream the inner maps 
         result.values().stream()
         // put all the Doubles in a single stream
        .flatMap(m->m.values().stream())
         // unbox the Doubles to primitive doubles
        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
         // and sum them
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only streams it might look like as follows:

```
Map<Region, Map<Status, Double>> result =
    groupedTrades
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Map.Entry::getKey, // Leave key as is
                 entry -> mapToDouble(entry.getValue(), MyClass::sumOfTrades))); // applies sumOfTrades (See below)
```

And we define little helper function, in order to keep our stream readable:

```
// Takes map which contains lists of trades and and applies function mapper, which returns T (might be double) on those lists
private static <T> Map<Status, T> mapToDouble(Map<Status, List<Trade>> trades, Function<List<Trade>, T> mapper) {
    return trades.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, // Leave key as is
                    entry -> mapper.apply(entry.getValue())));
}

// Takes a list of trades and returns its sum
private static double sumOfTrades(List<Trade> trades) {
    return trades.stream().mapToDouble(Trade::getAmount).sum();
}
```

**Bonus** - sum of all trades:

```
double sum =
    groupedTrades
        // get collection of "inner" maps
        .values()
        .stream()
        // get only their values as collection of lists 
        .map(Map::values)
        // map the collection into stream of lists
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        // map the collection stream of lists into stream of Trade values
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        // map Trade into double value - "amount"
        .mapToDouble(Trade::getAmount)
        // get the sum
        .sum();
```